# $a \in (0,1]$ satisfies $a^{2008} -2a +1 = 0$ and we define $S$ as $S=1+a+a^2+a^3........a^{2007}$. The sum of all possible value(s) of $S$ is?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, summation, geometric-progressions

This is **homework**.

Let $a \in (0,1]$ satisfies the equation $$a^{2008} -2a +1 = 0$$ 
and we define $S$ as $$S=1+a+a^2+a^3........a^{2007}$$

The sum of all possible value(s) of $S$ is?

### My Attempt

$a=1$ is obviously a solution.Hence one value of $S$ is $2008$.

To find other values of $S$, I need all the other solutions of $a$ lying between $0$ and $1$. When I graphed the function [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zgnvp1s7st), the other root was approximately coming out to be $0.5$. But I think that such a problem has to be solved exactly and no approximations are needed. Hence, I am stuck here.

Solutions should preferably not involve a calculator or any computer tool and use college level math only (since this problem was found in a college level book).

Comment: Note that $a^{2008} -1 = (a-1)(a^{2007}+\cdots +1) = (a-1)S.$

Comment: There is a root slightly above $x=0.5$ because $(\frac 12)^{2008}$ is very small and positive but with $x$ just greater than $0.5$ the function goes negative.  Alpha didn't find a nice expression, so I think we are stuck with numeric searching.  One step of Newton is easy to come close to.  We have $f(12)=\frac 1{2^{2008}}, f'(\frac 12)\approx -2,$ so the next iteration of $x$ is $\frac 12+\frac 1{2^{2009}}$  That should be close enough for any reasonable purpose.  As Armen Tsirunyan shows, we do not need the value to answer the question.

Comment: @Winther Sorry, reverted it. It was done by mistake, my bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $1$ is a solution to $a^{2008}−2a+1 = 0$ therefore $a^{2008}−2a+1$ can be divided by $a-1$. If you do so, you'll get $a^{2007}+a^{2006}+...+a^2+a-1$. Since it's trivially a monotonous function and has values of opposite signs at $0$ and $1$, it *must* have a single real root in the interval $(0;1)$. It is such a number $a$ that $a^{2007}+a^{2006}+...+a^2+a-1 = 0$. Therefore, $a^{2007}+a^{2006}+...+a^2+a+1 = 2$. So you get $S = 2$ for the other root.

The final answer is $2+2008 = 2010$

Comment: How can we be sure that the root $\in (0,1]$?

Comment: @PrashantGokhale: We can substitura 0 and 1 into the equation and observe that they have opposite signs.

Comment: @Winther: I am not saying you should substitute 0 and 1 into the original function. I am saying substitute them into $a^{2007}+...a-1$ which is strictly negative at $0$ and strictly positive at $1$

Comment: Ah I see, I misread it then. I'll remove the comment above.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Is it $$ a^{2007}+a^{2006}+...+a^2+a-1 = 0 $$ or $$ a^{2007}+a^{2006}+...+a^2-a+1 = 0 $$. I am getting the other one. Am I wrong.